# Incompatible type error on FragmentManager. Trying to launch a fragment on actionbar button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying launch a fragment `second_fragment_viewall.java` with its layout file  second_Fragment_layout on clicking a button on the action bar.

I am getting this error.

> Incompatible types
>
> Required: android.app.FragmentManager
>
> Found: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_add) {
        {
            new second_fragment_viewall();
            FragmentManager fragmentManagerone=getSupportFragmentManager();
            second_fragment_viewall=new     second_fragment_viewall();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=new fagmentManagerone.beginTransaction();
            FragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

What changes should i make, please help.

Comment: So do that ! Its clearly says to you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

by

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

change

```
FragmentManager fragmentManagerone = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

to

```
FragmentManager fragmentManagerone = getFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Android OS version of Fragment manager you need to use

```
FragmentManager fragmentManagerone = getFragmentManager();
```

i.e. in android.app.FragmentManager it is getFragmentManager only and not getSupportFragmentManager.to use getSupportFragmentManager you will need to add dependency for android.support.v4 library in your app dependencies... you can do that using File>Project Structure>under Modules select App>select dependencies tab>click on + sign>add library dependency...

Comment: ok thank you, when i initially used the import android.app.FragmentManager, i was getting the Call requires API 11 error hence i replaced it with import android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Now I have changed getSupportFragmentManager to getFragmentManager and android.support.v4.app.Fragment to import android.app.FragmentManager, now I am again back to square one, Call Requires API 11 error.

Comment: Added  @TargetApi(11), so it is okay now...

Comment: okk...yes...adding the call to include target API 11 is required...glad it solved your problem..PS-if u think my answer did remove the core error u were getting then please mark my answer as correct/accepted by clicking on correct tickmark